# Solving UnauthorizedAccessException issue for listing files

Tags: c#, .net, security, exception

Listing all files in a drive other than my system drive throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

How can I solve this problem?

Is there a way to grant my application the access it needs?

---

#### My code:

```
Directory.GetFiles("S:\\", ...)
```

Comment: Have you signed your application? What are your security settings?

Comment: No I didn't. I am just writing this app for myself.

Comment: What type of app?  WinForms?  ASP.NET?  Can you post some code?

Comment: Thanks, it's winforms. I will post a reply with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Not really but at least the source.

It was the SearchOption.AllDirectories option that caused the exception.

But when I just list the immediate files using Directories.GetFiles, it works.

This is good enough for me.

Any way to solve the recursive listing problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a class that will work:

```
public static class FileDirectorySearcher
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Search(string searchPath, string searchPattern)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = GetFileSystemEntries(searchPath, searchPattern);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            yield return file;
        }

        IEnumerable<string> directories = GetDirectories(searchPath);

        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            files = Search(directory, searchPattern);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetDirectories(string directory)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> subDirectories = null;
        try
        {
            subDirectories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }

        if (subDirectories != null)
        {
            foreach (string subDirectory in subDirectories)
            {
                yield return subDirectory;
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetFileSystemEntries(string directory, string searchPattern)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = null;
        try
        {
            files = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(directory, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                yield return file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can the use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> filesOrDirectories = FileDirectorySearcher.Search(@"C:\", "*.txt");

foreach (string fileOrDirectory in filesOrDirectories)
{
   // Do something here.
}
```

It's recursive, but the use of yield gives it a low memory footprint (under 10KB in my testing). If you want only files that match the pattern and not directories as well just replace `EnumerateFileSystemEntries` with `EnumerateFiles`.

Comment: Can it find a specific file? I tried it and in the // Do something here, I put Messagebox.show(fileOrDirectory) and nothing came up. I know for a fact that the file exists. The filename does contain spaces and is longer than 8 characters. Does that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Are *you* allowed to access the drive? Can the program access the drive when it's not run from Visual Studio? Are restrictive permissions defined in the project's Security page ("[Security Page, Project Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x61d3e3(VS.80).aspx)")?

Comment: Yes, I enabled click once security > full trust app. Is it enough?

Answer (score 1):

In .net core you can do something like this below. It can search for all subdirectories recursively with good performance and ignoring paths without access.
I also tried other methods found in 
[How to quickly check if folder is empty (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755574/how-to-quickly-check-if-folder-is-empty-net/755611#755611)  and 
[Is there a faster way than this to find all the files in a directory and all sub directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106877/is-there-a-faster-way-than-this-to-find-all-the-files-in-a-directory-and-all-sub?rq=1) and 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1383832/System-IO-Directory-Alternative-using-WinAPI

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ListFiles(string baseDir)
{
    EnumerationOptions opt = new EnumerationOptions();
    opt.RecurseSubdirectories = true;
    opt.ReturnSpecialDirectories = false;
    //opt.AttributesToSkip = FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.System;
    opt.AttributesToSkip = 0;
    opt.IgnoreInaccessible = true;

    var tmp = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(baseDir, "*", opt);
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: IgnoreInaccessible and ReturnSpecialDirectories was the trick for my case. +1