# How to get file with multiple extensions with recursion on C#?

Tags: c#

I want to get a file with multiple extensions with recursion on C#.

This is what I tried:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesByExtensions(this DirectoryInfo dir, params string[] extensions)
{
    if (extensions == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("extensions");

    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = dir.EnumerateFiles();

    return files.Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension));
}
```

And noticed that this not used this return files only from `TopDirectoryOnly`.
I try this modification:

```cs
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But this did not help. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method to get all files within folder and subfolders that will return a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305581/method-to-get-all-files-within-folder-and-subfolders-that-will-return-a-list)

Comment: Yes, tanks a lot