# c# - code to list all the folders and sub folders and files inside that sub folder

Tags: c#, file-io

I want to create a console application to list out all the all the folders and sub folders and files inside that sub folder i mean entire drive can anyone help me with it

I searched lot's of sites but its only showing code to print top folders and files

Comment: Look at this question for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106877/is-there-a-faster-way-than-this-to-find-all-the-files-in-a-directory-and-all-sub?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use `Directory.GetFiles();`

**Its slow** but if .NET4 use the `System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories` and `System.IO.DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` methods