# quick and dirty way to recursively collect files from sub directories?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, file, c#-4.0, directory

So I have a directory where a bunch of configuration files are stored, but now I also have several sub directories which also contain config files. I had a function for collecting all configuration files per station, but now it's only collecting files in the directory, not the sub folders. old code:

```
    string MasterList = "ConfigsForStation1.txt";
    string dirC = "..\\config\\Station1\\";
    foreach (FileInfo fileC in dirC.GetFiles())
            {
                if(!System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileC.FullName).EndsWith(".confg"))
                {     WriteToList(fileC,MasterList);}

    }
```

and now with this sub directory stuff implemented its more along these lines:

```
        string MasterList = ...;
        string dirC = ...;
        //collect files in sub directories substations 1 & 2
        foreach(DirectoryInfo Dx in dirC.GetDirectories())
        {   foreach(FileInfo fileC in Dx.GetFiles())
            {...}
        }
        //collect files in parent directory station 1
        foreach(FileInfo fileC in dirC.GetFiles())
        {...}
```

my question is: is there a cleaner way to collect files from all sub folders rather then nest a foreach inside of a foreach? and then do a third pass for the stuff in parent. It feels abit sloppy and I feel like theres some command like dirC.getAllsub() that will do so for me? just looking for hints and ideas to clean up the code.

Comment: You've used the term `recursive` but you've not implemented a truly recursive method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetFiles()` method will return them all in one shot:

```
String dirC = "..\\config\\Station1\\";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirC);
FileInfo[] fia = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (FileInfo fi in fia)
{
    //do something with the file
}
```

You can replace the search pattern `*.*` with whatever fits the files you are looking for, such as `*.cfg`.

Answer (score 2):

There's [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) to which you can pass a parameter of [`SearchOption.AllDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx) which you can use to tell it to recurse the files for you automatically.

You should be able to do something like:

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirC, "*.confg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    ... Do something with filename
```

Or if you need to process every file:

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirC, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    ... Do something with filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Directory.GetFiles()` with `SearchOption.AllDirectories`. That will automatically recurse for you.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to write this as a comment but stackoverflow wasn't letting me.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106877/is-there-a-faster-way-than-this-to-find-all-the-files-in-a-directory-and-all-sub?rq=1) which provides many ways to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

use Directory.GetFiles:

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```