# SSIS Script task to check if file exists in folder or not

Tags: c#, file, ssis, file-exists

I want to check to see if a file exists in a particular folder from SSIS. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can use this as your starting point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385251/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-folder

Comment: I'm using the below code
Dts.Variables("FileExists").Value = File.Exists(Dts.Variables("FileLocation").Value)
where FileExists is a boolean variable and "FileLocation" is a string variable with file path
Though the file is present in the folder, still it is giving False value.

Comment: Just curious if the solution given below was useful to you and if you were able to resolve your issue. Your feedback will be helpful to me and also the future visitors who be having similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Variables:

folder - string - C::\Temp\

file   - string - 1.txt

fileExists - boolean - False

```
public void Main()
{
    string folder = Dts.Variables["User::folder"].Value.ToString();     //@"C:\temp\";
    string file = Dts.Variables["User::file"].Value.ToString();         //"a.txt";
    string fullPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", folder, file);

    Dts.Variables["User::fileExists"].Value = File.Exists(fullPath);

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: I tried the answer above but I got an error when running the ssis in our environment.Exception has been thrown by the target invocation.

Comment: Please make sure that those variables are being passed to the script; folder and file as ReadOnly, fileExists as ReadWrite

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Foreach Loop Container` and simply place all your items into it. It will be executed if file exists and won't if not. Very simple :)

Comment: Very nice! I was looking for something simple and easy to implement and that works fine.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to having an "out" variable, you could also Change the `Dts.TaskResult` based on whether or not the file exists. The snippet below fails the script task if the file doesn't exist. (It also creates a log entry if logging is enabled.)

```
public void Main()
{
    string fileName = Dts.Variables["User::sourcePath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::fileName"].Value.ToString();

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    } 
    else 
    {
        Dts.Log(string.Format("File {0} was not found.",fileName),0,null);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no native tasks inside SSIS that can do this check but you can accomplish this using a Script Task but i suggest you check the following links for simple steps required to achieve that.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/76/does-file-exist-check-in-ssis

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/simple-effective-way-tell-whether-file-exists-using-ssis-package