# SSIS Package Source Check

Tags: sql, ssis, automation

I have an SSIS package that runs automatically once a month. It pulls data from two separate Excel Spreadsheets (in two separate folders) and compiles it into an SSRS Report for our VP's.

I have an issue with one of the data providers not putting his information into the folder at the appropriate time, thus causing the package to fail.

My Director now wants some checks put in place so that the package looks for the file first and if it's not their the Job will not attempt to run until the package is present.

Is this possible in SQL or do I need to find a customer resource to make this work?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568554/ssis-script-task-to-check-file-exists-in-folder-or-not

Answer (score 0):

You can also use xp_command shell to know if perticular file is present in perticular folder