# dynamic excel file generation duplicate records in ssis

Tags: excel, dynamic, ssis, duplicates, records

I am currently generating the excel files dynamically using foreach loop+file system task+ data flow task which will load data to the excel files.
But, when i am getting duplicate records instead of over writing already created excel file. I want the duplicate records to load into already created file.
For example if for one product there are four prod items having same name. The file created with a specific product should have all the product items in it.

Please suggest me a solution.
Since this is excel generation which is most hectic thing in ssis.. please try to provide soln elaborately.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I have seen, over-writing is not the default behavior of the Excel connection manager, so I do not know how you are getting this result.  You will need describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use a script task to see if the file exists.  If it does, delete the file and regenerate.

Here are examples:

- http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/simple-effective-way-tell-whether-file-exists-using-ssis-package
- http://sql-articles.com/articles/bi/file-exists-check-in-ssis/
- [SSIS Script task to check if file exists in folder or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568554/ssis-script-task-to-check-if-file-exists-in-folder-or-not)