# SSIS check if *.csv files exist in a folder

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I'm new to SSIS and am learning by the power of Google. I have a package but before it runs, I need to check if any csv exist in a folder.  If they do, then continue, otherwise stop.

I've been watching you tube videos like the below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgqyQm6EymU

but this only chekcs for a specific file - I need to check if any csv's exist in a folder regardless of there name - how do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a custom script.

See [SSIS Script task to check if file exists in folder or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568554/) for the details about hooking up the script task. You don't need the file and fullPath variables, just the folder variable.

Substitute [Directory.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx)(folder, "*.csv").Any() for File.Exists in the above link.

```
Dts.Variables["User::fileExists"].Value = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.csv").Any();
```

Comment: Hi there, I have the same problem as original poster, but I cant use your solution because I can not use .Any(), any ideas why?

Comment: @SQL_Noob .Any() is a Linq method. You might need to add the `using Sytesm.Linq` statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with the SSIS script component, you can use the
[File Properties Task](http://filepropertiestask.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.