# How to check any .txt file exists in a folder?

Tags: c#, file

How to check if any `.txt` file exists in a folder?

If the folder still have `.txt` file output a error messagebox.

Thx all! Actually i want to make a function can check any .txt file exists in a folder. If yes write a error message to eventLog.
Final My code:

```
     System.Diagnostics.EventLog appLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:/Users/Public/Definitions");
     FileInfo[] TXTFiles = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
     foreach (var fi in TXTFiles)
     {
         if (fi.Exists)
         {
             appLog.Source = "Definitions Folder still have text files";
             appLog.WriteEntry("Still have txt files.");
         }
     }
```

Comment: This question may have been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385251/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-folder

Comment: The question linked is a duplicate - but its accepted answer is old, and .net offers a better solution now with EnumerateFiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check like below :

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Directory");
FileInfo[] TXTFiles = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");
if (TXTFiles.Length == 0)
{
    //No files present
}
foreach (var file in TXTFiles)
{
    if(file.Exists)
    {
         //.txt File exists 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` like this:

```
if(Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, "*.txt",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Any())
   Foo();
```

> See more here [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
if(files.Length >= 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Message ... Your folder still have some Txt files left");
    // or
    Console.WriteLine("Error Message ... Your folder still have some Txt files left");
}
```