# C# Move Files From A Folder To Another (How to code: if doesn't exist do nothing)

Tags: c#

*Beginner: Here is my code:*

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;   

public void MoveFiles(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
        Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
        {
                if ("HOW TO CODE: If the sourceFiles exist in destFolder")
                {
                    File.Move(file, Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(file)));
                }
        });
    }
```

*I get an error if the source files exist in destination folder. How can I correct that and is there a better way to do that?*

Comment: `File.Exists(filePath)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a file exists in a folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385251/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-folder)

Comment: `if (files.Length>0) { Parallel....`

Comment: **It gives an error:** "

Cannot create a file when that file already exists."

Answer (score 2):

`File` has the static methods `Delete` and `Exists` you can use for that very case

```
if(File.Exists(file))
{
    if(File.Exists(destinationFile))
    {
        File.Delete(destinationFile);
    }
    File.Move(file, destinationFile);
}
```

I've used `destinationFile` to avoid redundancy.