# Fast I/O to check if directory contains files

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a C# application with .NET 4 to read and process data files (*.dat) from a list of directories.

Currently, I'm checking if a directory contains files using the following function:

```
    private bool FilesPresent()
    {
        string[] DIRS = Directory.GetDirectories(dataFileDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        foreach (string d in DIRS)
        {
            string[] FILES = Directory.GetFiles(d, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            if (FILES.Length > 0) { return true; }
        }
        return false;                
    }
```

I've also tried some alternative solutions from the following post: [How to quickly check if folder is empty (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755574/how-to-quickly-check-if-folder-is-empty-net)

It's important to note that some of the directories have in excess of 1,000,000 files. Even reading the million+ file names into a string[] is taking a long time.

How can I implement this differently so that it runs faster?

Putting it simply; I'd just like to know the fastest way of checking if the directory is not empty. I'm not concerned with retrieving the filenames at this time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to quickly check if folder is empty (.NET)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755574/how-to-quickly-check-if-folder-is-empty-net)

Comment: I don't think you'll get any faster than the top answer in that duplicate. Why isn't that suitable?

Comment: `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dataFileDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Any(d => Directory.EnumerateFiles(d, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any())`

Comment: Directory.EnumerateDirectories(folderPath,SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).SelectMany(x => x.EnumerateFiles()).Any();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach using LINQ and `EnumerateFileSystemEntries`+`AllDirectories`:

```
bool noFiles = !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(dataFileDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Any(entry => !File.GetAttributes(entry).HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory));
```

If `FileAttribute.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory)` returns `false` it is a file.

Comment: Wow! Now that is a lot faster! Thanks a lot for your answer, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from .NET 4.0 there are two methods, `EnumerateDirectories`/`EnumerateFiles` that lazily enumerate directories/files.

```
private static bool FilesPresent()
{
    IEnumerable<string> dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dataFileDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (string d in dirs)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(d, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        if (files.Any()) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Technically you could rewrite it as:

```
private static bool FilesPresent()
{
    IEnumerable<string> dirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dataFileDirectoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    return dirs.Any(d => Directory.EnumerateFiles(d, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any());
}
```

But I do feel it would make it more unreadable.