# C# Getting paths of all folders and subfolders, excluding folders with only other folders in them

Tags: c#, directory

I'm trying to obtain all of the folder paths that have files inside them, while excluding the folder paths that only have other folders in them. I'm using

```
Directory.GetDirectories(dirPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Which does what I need it to, except that it returns the paths of folders that only have other folders in them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fast I/O to check if directory contains files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605196/fast-i-o-to-check-if-directory-contains-files)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to `EnumerateFiles` for the directory and all it's sub-directories, and get a `Distinct()` list of their directory names:

```
List<string> directoriesWithFiles = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(rootDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(Path.GetDirectoryName)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

---

The first way I thought to do this was to use `EnumerateDirectories`, and then for each directory use `EnumerateFiles` to filter out directories that don't contain any files. But this turned out to be much slower than the method above:

```
List<string> directoriesWithFiles = Directory
    .EnumerateDirectories(rootDir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(d => Directory.EnumerateFiles(d).Any())
    .ToList();
```