# Summation of double using the processor's floating-point instruction set

Tags: c#

On a Windows machine with Intel Core-i5, I want to write a c# program which sums an array of double at **highest possible speed**, which in fact means **using the instruction set of the built-in FPU.**

```
double[] arr = new double[] { 1.123, 2.234, 3.1234, .... };
```

The processor has a built-in command which can sum up a whole memory array ("vector") with one single command. **Is there a way in C# to execute the summation with this built-in machine command?** ( I mean, besides writing unmanaged assembly code)

EDIT: Or is there a library call which will do this ?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't directly use SSE/AVX/... instructions in C#. You could write some C++ code and PInvoke it, but probably the PInvoke cost would remove all the benefits of using these instructions.

Technically you can do **bad things** and call these instructions from C# (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29646856/613130), but they are **bad *slow* things**, so you wouldn't probably gain anything speedwise.

Comment: hm, I somehow cannot believe this. I mean: All around the world we have millions of of Intel CPUs, millions of programmers are writing C# programs, amd many programs are doing data digging with millions of numbers. So, doesn't Microsoft's compiler+library  support that all these programs use the processor's higher instruction set ? That would be a total waste of machine power!

Comment: @StackWorm Sadly it is so. In the future (lets say 2 years), the new Ryujit compiler should solve this... See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/07/the-jit-finally-proposed-jit-and-simd-are-getting-married.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to accomplish this

```
double sum = arr.Sum();
```

which uses Linq to sum the array. This is the simplest way, but is not the highest possible speed way. You asked about a library call that can do this, HPCsharp is such a library: nuget package available on nuget.org. The fastest implementation there is

```
double sum = arr.SumSsePar();
```

which uses SIMD/SSE instructions to get the most performance out of each core, and uses multiple cores to get the highest performance out of the processor.