# Is there a performance impact when calling ToList()?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list

When using `ToList()`, is there a performance impact that needs to be considered?

I was writing a query to retrieve files from a directory, which is the query:

`string[] imageArray = Directory.GetFiles(directory);`

However, since I like to work with `List<>` instead, I decided to put in...

`List<string> imageList = Directory.GetFiles(directory).ToList();`

So, is there some sort of performance impact that should be considered when deciding to do a conversion like this - or only to be considered when dealing with a large number of files? Is this a negligible conversion?

Comment: +1 interested to know the answer here too. IMHO unless the app is performance critical, I think I'd always use a `List<T>` in favour of a `T[]` if it makes the code more logical/readable/maintainable (unless of course the conversion _was_ causing _noticeable_ performance problems in which case I'd re-visit it I guess).

Comment: Creating a list from an array should be super cheap.

Comment: @Sepster I only specify the data type as specifically as I need to do a job. If I don't have to call `Add` or `Remove`, I would leave it as `IEnumerable<T>` (or even better `var`)

Comment: I think, in this case it's better to call `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles`, so only one array will be created.

Comment: If you have lot of files in the directory see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865159/retrieving-files-from-directory-that-contains-large-amount-of-files/7865180#7865180

Comment: `GetFiles(directory)`, as it is implemented in .NET currently, pretty much does `new List<string>(EnumerateFiles(directory)).ToArray()`. So `GetFiles(directory).ToList()` creates a list, creates an array from that, then creates a list again. Like 2kay says, you should be preferring to do `EnumerateFiles(directory).ToList()` here.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

### `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()`

Yes, [`IEnumerable<T>.ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) does have a performance impact, it is an *O(n)* operation though it will likely only require attention in performance critical operations.

The `ToList()` operation will use the [`List(IEnumerable<T> collection)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) constructor. This constructor must make a copy of the array (more generally `IEnumerable<T>`), otherwise future modifications of the original array will change on the source `T[]` also which wouldn't be desirable generally.

I would like to reiterate this will only make a difference with a huge list, copying chunks of memory is quite a fast operation to perform.

### Handy tip, `As` vs `To`

You'll notice in LINQ there are several methods that start with `As` (such as [`AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx)) and `To` (such as [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)). The methods that start with `To` require a conversion like above (ie. may impact performance), and the methods that start with `As` do not and will just require some cast or simple operation.

### Additional details on `List<T>`

Here is a little more detail on how `List<T>` works in case you're interested :)

A `List<T>` also uses a construct called a dynamic array which needs to be resized on demand, this resize event copies the contents of an old array to the new array. So it starts off small and [increases in size if required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15446006/1156119).

This is the difference between the [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx) and [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) properties on [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). `Capacity` refers to the size of the array behind the scenes, `Count` is the number of items in the `List<T>` which is always `<= Capacity`. So when an item is added to the list, increasing it past `Capacity`, the size of the `List<T>` is doubled and the array is copied.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that `List(IEnumerable<T> collection)` constructor checks if collection parameter is `ICollection<T>` and then creates a new internal array with required size right away. If parameter collection is not `ICollection<T>`, constructor iterates through it and calls `Add` for each element.

Comment: It is important to note that you may often see ToList() as a misleadingly demanding operation. This happens when you create an IEnumerable<> througha LINQ query. the linq query is constructed but not executed. calling ToList() will run the query and therefore seem resource intensive - but it is the query that is intensive and not the ToList() operation (Unless it is a really huge list)

Answer (score 42):

> Is there a performance impact when calling toList()?

Yes of course. Theoretically even `i++` has a performance impact, it slows the program for maybe a few ticks.

**What does `.ToList` do?**

When you invoke `.ToList`, the code calls `Enumerable.ToList()` which is an extension method that `return new List<TSource>(source)`. In the corresponding constructor, *under the worst circumstance,* it goes through the item container and add them one by one into a new container. So its behavior affects little on performance. It's impossible to be a performance bottle neck of your application.

**What's wrong with the code in the question**

`Directory.GetFiles` goes through the folder and returns all files' names *immediately* into memory, it has a potential risk that the string[] costs a lot of memory, slowing down everything.

**What should be done then**

It depends. If you(as well as your business logic) gurantees that the file amount in the folder is always small, the code is acceptable. But it's still suggested to use a lazy version: `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in C#4. This is much more like a query, which will not be executed immediately, you can add more query on it like:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath).Any(s => s.Contains("myfile"))
```

which will stop *searching* the path as soon as a file whose name contains "myfile" is found. This is obviously has a better performance then `.GetFiles`.

Answer (score 23):

> Is there a performance impact when calling toList()?

Yes there is. Using the extension method `Enumerable.ToList()` will construct a new `List<T>` object from the `IEnumerable<T>` source collection which of course has a performance impact.

However, understanding `List<T>` may help you determine if the performance impact is significant.

`List<T>` uses an array (`T[]`) to store the elements of the list. Arrays cannot be extended once they are allocated so `List<T>` will use an over-sized array to store the elements of the list. When the `List<T>` grows beyond the size the underlying array a new array has to be allocated and the contents of the old array has to be copied to the new larger array before the list can grow.

When a new `List<T>` is constructed from an `IEnumerable<T>` there are two cases:

1. The source collection implements `ICollection<T>`: Then `ICollection<T>.Count` is used to get the exact size of the source collection and a matching backing array is allocated before all elements of the source collection is copied to the backing array using `ICollection<T>.CopyTo()`. This operation is quite efficient and probably will map to some CPU instruction for copying blocks of memory. However, in terms of performance memory is required for the new array and CPU cycles are required for copying all the elements.
2. Otherwise the size of the source collection is unknown and the enumerator of `IEnumerable<T>` is used to add each source element one at a time to the new `List<T>`. Initially the backing array is empty and an array of size 4 is created. Then when this array is too small the size is doubled so the backing array grows like this 4, 8, 16, 32 etc. Every time the backing array grows it has to be reallocated and all elements stored so far have to be copied. This operation is much more costly compared to the first case where an array of the correct size can be created right away.

   Also, if your source collection contains say 33 elements the list will end up using an array of 64 elements wasting some memory.

In your case the source collection is an array which implements `ICollection<T>` so the performance impact is not something you should be concerned about unless your source array is very large. Calling `ToList()` will simply copy the source array and wrap it in a `List<T>` object. Even the performance of the second case is not something to worry about for small collections.

Answer (score 6):

It will be as (in)efficient as doing:

```
var list = new List<T>(items);
```

If you disassemble the source code of the constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`, you will see it will do a few things:

- Call `collection.Count`, so if `collection` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, it will force the execution. If `collection` is an array, list, etc. it should be `O(1)`.
- If `collection` implements `ICollection<T>`, it will save the items in an internal array using the `ICollection<T>.CopyTo` method. It *should* be `O(n)`, being `n` the length of the collection.
- If `collection` does not implement `ICollection<T>`, it will iterate through the items of the collection, and will add them to an internal list.

So, yes, it will consume more memory, since it has to create a new list, and **in the worst case, it will be `O(n)`**, since it will iterate through the `collection` to make a copy of each element.

Comment: close, `0(n)` where `n` is the total sum of bytes the strings in the original collection occupy, not the count of the elements (well to be more exact n = bytes/word size)

Comment: @user1416420 I might be wrong, but why is that? What if it is a collection of some other type (eg. `bool`, `int`, etc.)? You don't really have to make a copy of each string in the collection. You just add them to the new list.

Comment: still doesn't matter the new memory allocation & copying of bytes is what is killing this method. A bool will also occupy 4 bytes in .NET. Actually each reference of an object in .NET is at least 8 bytes long, so it's pretty slow. the first 4 bytes point to the type table & the second 4 bytes point to the value or memory location where to find the value

Answer (score 5):

`ToList()` creates a new List and put the elements in it which means that there is an associated cost with doing `ToList()`. In case of small collection it won't be very noticeable cost but having a huge collection can cause a performance hit in case of using ToList.

Generally you should not use ToList() unless work you are doing cannot be done without converting collection to List. For example if you just want to iterate through the collection you don't need to perform ToList

If you are performing queries against a data source for example a Database using LINQ to SQL then the cost of doing ToList is much more because when you use ToList with LINQ to SQL instead of doing Delayed Execution i.e. load items when needed (which can be beneficial in many scenarios) it instantly loads items from Database into memory

Comment: Haris :what i am not sure about the original source what will happen to the original source after calling to the ToList()

Comment: @Saurabh GC will clean it up

Comment: @Saurabh nothing will happen to original source. Elements of original source will be referenced by the newly created list

Comment: "if you just want to iterate through the collection you don't need to perform ToList" - so how should you iterate?

Answer (score 5):

> "is there a performance impact that needs to be considered?"

The issue with your precise scenario is that first and foremost your real concern about performance would be from the hard-drive speed and efficiency of the drive's cache.

From that perspective, the impact is surely negligible to the point that **NO** it need not be considered.

BUT ONLY if you really need the features of the `List<>` structure to possibly either make you more productive, or your algorithm more friendly, or some other advantage.  Otherwise,  you're just purposely adding an insignificant performance hit, for no reason at all. In which case, naturally, you shouldn’t do it! :)

Answer (score 3):

Considering the performance of retrieving file list, `ToList()` is negligible. But not really for other scenarios. That really depends on where you are using it.

- When calling on an array, list, or other collection, you create a copy of the collection as a `List<T>`. The performance here depends on the size of the list. You should do it when really necessary.

  In your example, you call it on an array. It iterates over the array and adds the items one by one to a newly created list. So the performance impact depends on the number of files.
- When calling on an  `IEnumerable<T>`, you *materialize* the `IEnumerable<T>` (usually a query).

Answer (score 2):

ToList Will create a new list and copy elements from original source to the newly created list so only thing is to copy the elements from the original source and depends on the source size

Answer (score 0):

Let's look for another example;

If you working on databases when you run `ToList()` method and check the SQL Profiler for this code;

```
var IsExist = (from inc in entities.be_Settings                                
 where inc.SettingName == "Number"                                
 select inc).ToList().Count > 0;
```

Auto created query will like this:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[SettingName] AS [SettingName], [Extent1].[SettingValue] AS [SettingValue] FROM [dbo].[be_Settings] AS [Extent1] WHERE N'Number' = [Extent1].[SettingName]
```

The select query is run with the ToList method, and the results of the query are stored in memory, and it is checked whether there is a record by looking at the number of elements of the List. For example, if there are 1000 records in your table with the relevant criteria, these 1000 records are first brought from the database and converted into objects, and then they are thrown into a List and you only check the number of elements of this List. So this is very inefficient way to choose.

Answer (score -1):

its not exactly about list perfomance but if u have high dimensional array
u can use HashSet instead of List.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).