# Refactor Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to cut this linq down

```
 var sys = db.tlkpSystems
 .Where(a => db.tlkpSettings.Where(e => e.Hidden < 3)
 .Select(o => o.System)
 .ToList().Contains(a.System))      //cannot get this part in?
 .OrderBy(a => a.SystemName).ToList();

foreach (var item in sys)
    model.Add(new SettingSystem { 
        System = item.System, 
        SystemName = item.SystemName 
});
```

I have tried the following:

```
   List<SettingSystem> model = new List<SettingSystem>();
   model = db.tlkpSettings.Where(e => e.Hidden < 3)
     .OrderBy(e => e.Setting)
     .Select(e => new SettingSystem
     {
      System = e.System,
      SystemName = e.Setting
      }).ToList();
```

How can I call the .Contains(a.System) part in my query?

Thanks

Comment: @Mafii any reason why .ToList() should not be used? I am new to linq

Comment: Is this LINQ to Entities query?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516462/is-there-a-performance-impact-when-calling-tolist

Comment: @IvanStoev yes it is

Comment: Ok. What is the problem? Are you getting runtime exception?

Comment: Problem is I cannot figure out how to do this part in my version of linq .ToList().Contains(a.System))      //cannot get this part in?

Comment: @MelanciaUK Please read [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) before making further recommendations to sites you don't even have a profile for.

Comment: @Mafii Code Review deals with code that works as intended. This code clearly doesn't work as intended. Please refrain from recommending sites you don't have a user profile for and/or aren't familiar with.

Comment: What is the type of `System` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some general rules when working with LINQ to Entities:

- Avoid using `ToList` inside the query. It prevents EF to build a correct SQL query.
- Don't use `Contains` when working with entities (tables). Use `Any` or joins.

Here is your query (in case `System` is not an entity navigation property):

```
var sys = db.tlkpSystems
    .Where(a => db.tlkpSettings.Any(e => e.Hidden < 3 && e.System == a.System))
    .OrderBy(a => a.SystemName).ToList();
```

Comment: Seems like the `ToList()` isn't needed since all he does is iterate.

Comment: to list is needed as I return a list

Comment: @EdT Correct, the above is just to present the solution of the problematic part of the OP original query. Instead of `sys` variable and `ToList` \, he can add `.Select(...).ToList()` and get directly the result as in the second query.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum, there is also [`AsEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx) for when you *must* pull a query into memory (such as calling methods within another clause). This is generally better than [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`ToArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx) since it'll enumerate the query, rather than enumerating, putting together a `List`/`Array`, and then enumerating that collection.