# Listing a very large number of files in a directory in C#

Tags: c#, file, directory, enumeration

I'm trying to get a list of files in a specific directory that contains over 20 million files ranging from 2 to 20 KB each.
The problem is that my program throws the Out Of Memory Exception everytime, while tools like robocopy are doing a good job copying the folder to another directory with no problem at all. Here's the code I'm using to enumerate files:

```
            List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchDir));
```

What should I do to solve this problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't create a list of the files.  Just iterate over the result of `EnumerateFiles` and do whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to hold that much data in memory?On way you can do is create sub directory and break it into groups.

Comment: @Rohit Yes. I was trying to create a list, then iterate over them and do some processing.

Comment: @juharr I'm going to try it right now and let you know of the result

Comment: @JeremyMc -- What happens if you change `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to `Directory.GetFiles`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving files from directory that contains large amount of files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865159/retrieving-files-from-directory-that-contains-large-amount-of-files)

Comment: @JeremyMc Would need to see more code to determine if there are any other potential memory issues.

Comment: @rory.ap That would be even worse as it would return an array of the files then create a list from that array, thus doubling the amount of memory used.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, It worked perfectly.  Habib wrote it as a post & I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are creating a list of 20 million object in memory. I don't think you will ever use that, even if it become possible.

Instead use to `Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchDir)` and iterate each item one by one.

like:

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchDir))
{
   //Copy to other location, or other stuff
}
```

With your current code, your program will have 20 million objects first loaded up in memory and then you have to iterate, or perform operations on them.

See: [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use **EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of
>   names before the whole collection is returned;** when you use
>   GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned
>   before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with
>   many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

Comment: Isn't that going to run into the same problem?

Comment: @rory.ap, not it will not. This will not load up the 20 million files path in memory, instead it will be one object *(string path)* at a time in memory

Comment: @GillBates, no. Enumeration, doesn't mean returning collection. This will do lazy evaluation. Just like `File.ReadLine` vs `File.ReadAllLines`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above covers one directory level. To be able to enumerate through multiple levels of directories, each having a large number of directories with a large number of files, one can do the following:

```
public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string startingDirectoryPath) {
    var directoryEnumerables = new Queue<IEnumerable<string>>();
    directoryEnumerables.Enqueue(new string[] { startingDirectoryPath });
    while (directoryEnumerables.Any()) {
        var currentDirectoryEnumerable = directoryEnumerables.Dequeue();
        foreach (var directory in currentDirectoryEnumerable) {
            foreach (var filePath in EnumerateFiles(directory)) {
                yield return filePath;
            }
            directoryEnumerables.Enqueue(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory));
        }                
    }
}
```

The function will traverse a collection of directories through enumerators, so it will load the directory contents one by one. The only thing left to solve is the depth of the hierarchy...

Comment: I guess fileEnumeratorFunc does not exist?