# C# Directory.GetFiles() with wildcard filter show unpredictable results

Tags: c#

I am using the following C# code to filter a directory containing multiple files:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDatafiles, @"2022*.txt",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

The directory contains multiple files for instance files like:
2022-07-21-14.txt
2017-2-2-0.txt

The result of the filter is wrong: It also filters the second file name as a valid name. But it does not contain "2022" !?
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: Please provide the content of the directory you are using this code on (i.e. output of `DIR /x | findtr "2022"` )

Comment: 10/02/2014  08:04 AM             4,265 202261~1.TXT 2014-10-1-22.txt
10/20/2014  09:01 AM             4,265 202205~1.TXT 2014-10-20-7.txt, the output contains "2022" :).  Directory resides on m:/ disk. Same result in the c:/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could share more information on your environment, DotNet framework version, OS etc.

When I run the below code using DotNet 6 on Windows I get the expected results, namely it only prints the file 2022-07-14.txt

```
string SourceDatafiles = @"C:\Temp\Test";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDatafiles, @"2022*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

foreach (var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Comment: Windows 10 HOME,  .NETFramework,Version=v4.5", Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, NTFS.

Comment: Problem still exits after installing .NET6.0.   BUT: I got it working using both platforms using only a small amount of files in the source-directory. In that case it workes as intended. In my case the source-directory contains more than 5000 files , then the unexpected result show up!?

Comment: Correction: 75000 files; no exceptions occurred.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39753445/19595774 I will give this a try, a better approach I guess. Still wondering why the wild-card filter did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39753445/19595774

```
int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
string pattern = "2022"; 
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir))
{
    if (file.Contains("2022"))
        Console.WriteLine("Index:" + count1++ + "Name:" + file); 
    /* OR */
    if (Regex.IsMatch(file, pattern) )
        Console.WriteLine("Index:" + count2++ + "Name:" + file);
}
```

Enumeration works fine. I think a better approach than `Directory.GetFiles(SourceDatafiles, @"2022*.txt",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)`.
Still wondering why the wild-card filter did not work as expected.