# Counting number of files on a drive

Tags: c#, io

I need my program to count the number of files on a disk drive.

What is the fastest way to do so?

Directory.GetFiles() is not an alternative, as it is very slow.

Comment: What kind of an answer is that? There must be some way, we have NTFS journal, we have the WMI and so on lol

Comment: It is a _comment_ on the question, not an answer. And you simply say the `GetFiles` "is slow". What is fast, in your definition? The question lacks detail.

Comment: if you have NTFS journal, then is possible to do Directory.GetFiles() on start and then using journal maintain counter.

Comment: Did you try accessing the MFT directly?

Comment: @user92546 No, because my program needs to support FAT file systems too. :(

Comment: @user92546 Windows doesn't allow direct access to the sectors

Comment: @ColeJohnson - The OP is disappointed with the performance of the OS, so an end run is an option.  It ought to be possible to mount the volume privately and access it as an array of blocks.  (There was no requirement stated to play nicely with others.)  For those with strong stomachs some PInvoke code may be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c1550294-d121-4511-ac32-31551497f64e/).

Comment: working with MFT is fast, yes , but what I need is a solution that works both for FAT and NTFS...

Comment: there is no solution which is faster than GetFiles, which also supports FAT file systems. the most time consuming factor is the random seek of the hard disc to read a new sector (good random read operations per seconds on magnetic hard drives are about 100 - 500), e.g. having 10.000 folders can make this quite slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try import `kernel32.dll` and use it?

There is a good implementation example someone posted before here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/724184/912851. It might be worthwhile looking at.

**Edit:**
The fastest one I saw in my life is [this application](http://www.voidtools.com/download.php). It uses ntfs journals. and within seconds it lists millions of files on my harddisk.
I think they have a sdk and sources on C++ or c. Maybe you can create a managed dll and use on c#?

Comment: I was curious so I made a small code to compare both methods on directory tree with 42k files: GetFiles=1.2seconds, this method=650ms. So it's already 2x faster... As Oded already write above, IO is slow, you'll not have immediate result for hundred of thousands files...

Answer (score 0):

you could read out the drive USN journal, this is very fast but you need administrator rights

Answer (score -2):

```
Func<string, int> files = null;
files = p => Directory.GetFiles(p).Length() + Directory.GetDirectories(p).Select(p1 => files(p1));

int count = files(@"c:\");
```

Horrible but linqy!

Comment: Directory.GetFiles() is not an alternative ^^

Comment: How is this addressing the _slowness_ issue the OP is asking about?

Comment: Horrible, use GetFiles, and ... doesn't compile :p

Comment: Lol, @all, I wouldn't consider this a serious answer, but its the shortest method I know of counting all the files on the drive. The reality is, as has been said, IO is slow regardless.