# Get count of files from directory without enumerating files in c#

Tags: c#, file, directory

I am using     `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` and `Directory.GetFiles()` to get the count of files in a specific directory in c#. The problem is that theses methods are slow because they enumerate files to get there count.

How to get the count of files in Directory without enumerating files in c#?

Comment: Short answer: No there isn't. Even if you get some API to do that, It will enumerate internally.

Comment: but if the directory contains a lot of files (more than 50000) it takes too time. this is not possible

Answer (score 9):

You **have to** enumerate through the folder in order to get all the files.

However, you can still do something to improve the performance. I suggest you have a look at those benchmark tests (Get1 method):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17756559/3876750

It seems like the following method provides the best performance, according to the benchmark test:

```
private static int Get1(string myBaseDirectory)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(myBaseDirectory);
    return dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories()
           .AsParallel()
           .SelectMany(di => di.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
           .Count();
}
```

Comment: Am I doing something odd or does this not search the baseDir for files also?

Comment: Ah it's because it is enumerating the directories, but doesn't search itself.

Answer (score 4):

I actually never tried a faster way but its a good question.. By searching I've found this

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38959/A-Faster-Directory-Enumerator

The Benchmark comparison looks quite nice..

MayBe this helps..

Comment: I've used the FastDirectoryEnumerator class a number of times, and it's ridiculously faster than all of the built-in methods for enumeration. It achieves this by avoiding large pre-allocations, caching intermediate results, and running tasks in parallel. Highly recommended!

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to use **Directory.GetFiles()** or the **DirectoryInfo** class.

The Advantage is, that you can use an overload of GetFIles to search for files inside subdirectories e.g.

```
int allfilesCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
```

[MSDN DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Mybe you could try

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles().Count()
```

if it is faster.

Answer (score -2):

hi maybe this help it return string[]

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries("path");
```