# Scanning folders via multiple threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, threadpool, bulkinsert

I am scanning the folder in network drive through iteration (do while loop basically).To speed up the process I need to utilize the threading or task for each folder and get result in List having attributes path,filename,lastwriteutc,size. I have done below.

```
string startFolder = @"D:\Development\TempScan";
string startFolder2 = @"D:\RemotePc";
List<string> foldersToScan = new List<string>();
foldersToScan.Add(startFolder);
foldersToScan.Add(startFolder2);

foreach (var folder in foldersToScan)
{
Thread thread = new Thread(() => IterateFolder(findInfoLevel, additionalFlags, folder))
{
      Name = "Thread " + folder

};

thread.Start();
Console.WriteLine(thread.Name.ToLower() + " has started");
//thread.Join();
}
// Database operation here
```

If I used `thread.Join()` method code become synchronous and then only I can perform database operation and if i dont used `thread.Join()` then database operation will be called before scanning operation.

I have also used Task as below but its also synchronous

```
Task task1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
foreach (var folder in foldersToScan)
{
IterateFolder(findInfoLevel, additionalFlags, folder);
}
});
task1.Wait();
```

How to achieve asynchronous scanning of folders one thread per folder and once I get result  asynchronous database insertion?

Comment: @stuartd can you give some reference or example available.

Comment: Look at `Parallel.For` or `task.WhenAll` instead of manually creating threads. But start by looking at [faster file enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756042/improve-the-performance-for-enumerating-files-and-folders-using-net).

Comment: `Task.Run` isn't synchronous. The code executes in the background. `Wait()` is a blocking call though. if you want to scan multiple paths concurrently you need to start multiple tasks and await all of them with `await Task.WhenAll()`

Comment: @JonasH  I have used win32 API for iterating the folder as it is 20 time faster than regular inbuilt function available in .net

Comment: Don't expect huge improvements from running scans in parallel. A network drive might be limited by network and disc IO limits with regards to concurrent access. Do some rough tests before going all out on coding tasks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you got me right , thanks any example if you can share :)

Comment: @EmondErno you are right , but let me achieve parallel or async task before reaching conclusion

Comment: My point is that a simple, rough test might make it clear if it is possible/worth it at all. I'd split it up in two two parallel threads  and measure to see if there are any improvements before diving in and writing a bunch of code that cannot succeed. Measure before optimizing. Note that I am not saying that it is impossible.

Comment: Do keep in mind that starting a thread allocates a 1MB stack for each one. If you have a million folders then you're going to kill your process.

Comment: @Enigmativity thx for information!! Any alternate solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();

foreach (var folder in foldersToScan)
{
    var thread = new Thread(() => IterateFolder(findInfoLevel, additionalFlags, folder))
    {
        Name = "Thread " + folder
    };

    thread.Start();
    Console.WriteLine(thread.Name.ToLower() + " has started");
    threads.Add(thread);
}

foreach(var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

This way the code waits/blocks until all threads are done. You could/should make this more robust: error handling, time-outs or switching to Tasks.

Comment: is it is working asynchronously :) what trick :) Many Thanks , can you elaborate more about things you mentioned in comment for making robust  and learning example online available :)

Comment: var threads = new Thread(() => IterateFolder(findInfoLevel, additionalFlags, folder))
    {
        Name = "Thread " + folder
    };   in above code just typo mistake remove "s" in threads

Comment: Fixed. Thanks! As for adding improvements: thread.Join can take a time-out as a parameter and will return a boolean that indicates if the thread returned within the time out. So that would allow you to check for that and add an if in the foreach loop. Adding an exception handler (try...catch) can be done in the loop as well. I am not adding these because how you code them depends largely on what the program needs to happen in those cases (retry, resume, fail, abort) and that would distract from the answer to the original question.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use Linq:

```
foldersToScan.AsParallel().Where( f => IterateFolder( findInfoLevel, additionalFlags, f ) );
```

[Here](https://thedeveloperblog.com/c-sharp/asparallel) are some more examples how to use `AsParallel()` from Linq.

To make it asynchron, you can put this in one single BackgroundWorker or Thread.