What is the fastest way to get the number of files contained in a directory, including its subdirectories in Windows using .NET?
I have a directory that contains subdirectories, and each of those contains a good number of files. Each such directory contains at least 100k total files within its subdirectories, with each subdirectory directly containing about 150 files each. I want to show the total count of files within the directory, including all its subdirectories' file counts. While I can do this by using the .NET APIs in System.IO, is there a better way?

The absolute fastest is to run as administrator and parse the $MFT file table, see eg WizTree which does this. Very complex though.

Similar question asked and answered 15 years ago. The version that explicitly calls the Windows API FindFirst and FindNext is the fastest. But the versions that use either Directory.EnumerateFiles or Directory.GetDirectories and Directory.GetFiles are a whole lot easier to code and are fast enough for most purposes. https://stackoverflow.com/q/724148/56778

This is about only getting the number of contained files, without caring about the names and properties of the files themselves. The question is not exactly the same. And yes, the fastest way is tricker to implement, which is why I released the package I mention below. So it should be trivial to use the better method.

Using just .NET's standard library, the fastest option is
int count = Directory.EnumerateFiles(...).Count();

However, there's other posts asking about listing directories and subdirectories fast, and through research I came up with a faster implementation, in this repository (NuGet).
DISCLAIMER: The author of the linked repository is myself. As also mentioned in the README, the code was taken by this post, and the package is being released under the CPOL license as was the original code of the post's author, wilsone8. I have only tested this in local drives. The author of the original post mentioned using their approach for files over network, and the final code uses the same APIs for enumerating the files, so there's high chance this works for network files too.
The package provides a method to get the file count, which you can use like so:
// ensure the using:
using FastDiskIO;

var count = FastDirectoryEnumeration.GetFileCount(
    "dir/path/",
    searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Example for 300k files spread within 300 subdirectories:



Method
Mean
Ratio
Allocated
Alloc Ratio




GetFileCount
111.1 ms
0.95
99.25 KB
0.004


Directory_EnumerateFiles
116.6 ms
1.00
25741.13 KB
1.000



The allocations are avoided by reusing the same struct when invoking the Windows APIs, and only allocating strings that are required for calculating the path of the subdirectories to iterate next.
And for the above example, it seems that we have hit the API/IO bottleneck, so it can probably be barely improved. The major impact is the allocation reduction though, which is huge for much denser and more packed directories.

This is likely to be the fastest and most memory-efficient approach possible, since it just uses the Windows API FindFirstFile and FindNextFile. There is no faster way to count files.

Simply linking to wilsone8's original project is not sufficient.  Neither the GitHub project nor your answer attributes the original author, wilsone8.  I checked and the GitHub project is more than just inspired by the CodeProject.  It's unambiguously a derivative work.  You can see the preserved code in multiple places, including FileEnumerator.
Your answer claims, "The author of the linked repository is myself." when you are only one of the coauthors.

This is not just an attribution failure.  It's also a violation of the original license, the Code Project Open License (CPOL) 1.02.  Your GitHub project purports to be licensed under the MIT license, while CPOL requires "You may distribute the Executable Files and Source Code only under the terms of this License [...] You may not sublicense the Work."

CPOL also requires, "You may otherwise modify Your copy of this Work (excluding the Articles) in any way to create a Derivative Work, provided that You insert a prominent notice in each changed file stating how, when and where You changed that file."
Please correct your GitHub project to comply with the license and attribute the original author.

@MatthewFlaschen updated the license in the repo, the package and this post. Please take a look

@Rekkon Thank you for responding.  Please also add the original author's name in the repo README and comply with the  "insert a prominent notice in each changed file stating how, when and where You changed that file" requirement from the CPOL.

@MatthewFlaschen updated again, please check
